# finding a sed match from variables located in another file using while loop

Tags: bash, sed

I have thousands of files here which i have to do a replace on. SO i am trying to create a bash program which will loop through all the old variables and replace them with new variables. So here is what i have currently.

I have a file with all the old and new variables for example: So i would need to replace the first value with the second value. I have named this file new.

```
web_lgl,web_lgl_index
web_matchmaker,web_matchmaker_index
web_mds,web_mds_index
web_metadata,web_metadata_index
web_mqmon,web_mqmon_index
web_pdconfig,web_pdconfig_index
web_people,web_people_index
web_pescado,web_pescado_index
```

now i have written a while loop as follows

```
while IFS="," read old new; do
find . -name "savedsearches.conf" -exec sed "s/$old/$new/g" '{}' \; 
done < new
```

this does work. it replaces the old value with the new value. but in the savedsearches.conf file i am trying to target specific strings to get replaced for example

```
index="web_lgl"
index = "web_matchmaker"
index= "web_pdconfig"
```

and not some random sentence in the file like for example

```
description: web_lgl contains AWS data. which is collected from AWS.
```

SO i need to tweak my bash script so that i can target only the variables with index= as the starting part and ignore every other occurence of the string. I have tried adding index= to the bash program but i am not getting any hits. for example the below code does not produce any hits.

```
while IFS="," read old new; do
find . -name "savedsearches.conf" -exec sed "s/index=$old/index=$new/g" '{}' \; 
done < new
```

Is there any way to tweak my bash script so that it specifically targets values after index= instead of any random sentence that the find command finds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regular expression in sed should only do the substitution on lines starting with `index`.

```
while IFS="," read old new; do
find . -name "savedsearches.conf" -exec sed "/^index/s/index=$old/index=$new/g" '{}' \; 
done < new
```

Comment: This approach will work. Thanks @Anthony.